# Передача 1 байта через сокет. Где застревает?

Tags: java, сокет, byte, echo

Пытаюсь передать 1 байт через сокет. Сервер должен его вернуть клиенту. Но почему-то оба застревают на чтении. Помогите разобраться, где застревает этот байт?

Код сервера:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            DataInputStream istream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream ostream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ) {
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        int result = istream.readByte();
        System.out.println("Server received: " + result);
        ostream.writeByte(result);
        ostream.flush();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            DataInputStream istream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream ostream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ) {
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        ostream.writeByte(10);
        ostream.flush();
        int result = istream.readByte();
        System.out.println("Client received: " + result);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Используется java 1.8.0_111

Если переделать клиент с отправкой второго байта, а на сервере поставить sleep в конце, то первый байт успешно приходит на сервер и возвращается к клиенту.

```
ostream.writeByte(10);
ostream.writeByte(11);
```

Comment: вроде воспроизводится на win7 с включенным Kaspersky Internet Security 17. Похоже, что если писать в поток только байты 10 и 13 (0x0A, 0x0D, символы перевода строки), то запись просто игнорируется (в wireshark ничего нет). После приостановки защиты через некоторое время код работает.

Comment: Касперского у меня нет, JRE1.8.0_111, код работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Неудачно я выбрал значение байта. Значения 10 и 13 Касперский съедает. Не знал, что требуется время для эффекта приостановки защиты. Без него всё работает, как ожидается.

Comment: @ilsu87 тогда имеет смысл разместить решение (отключение Касперского) как ответ и принять его. Думаю, это пригодится другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в поведении Kaspersky Internet Security.
Проверено с установленной версией KIS 17.0.0.611 под Windows 10 Home.

Решение:

1. Приостановить защиту (антивирусы, экраны, файрволы).
2. Подождать некоторое время (хватило 20 секунд).